# Unable to pass a firebase storage download URL to a interface property

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am uploading an file to firebase storage. Then I am getting the file URL as below

```
        snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(rawFileURL) {
        console.log("File available at", rawFileURL);
        this.downloadURL = rawFileURL;
        });
```

Now I am trying to pass this attribute to an interface which I want to submit to the firestore document. Like this.

```
    let sData: Data = {
      rawfilepath: this.downloadURL, // I also tried passing rawFileURL
      //rawfilepath: audioImagesRef.toString(),
      readyfilepath: "",
      teller: form.value.steller,
      title: form.value.stitle,
      userid: uid,
    }
```

I get the following error while submitting the interface properties to firestore

> ERROR FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field rawfilepath)

If I pass a normal string "" or say user.id to the interface, it works fine. But when I try to store downloadURL in the rawfilepath, it errors out.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is hard the see the problem with available data, it is safe to assume that you are assigning the `this.downloadURL` before it has a value in it. `snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()` returns a promise which run asynchronously not in order with the codes before or after.

A sample usage for your case would be;

```
let sData: Data;
    
snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(rawFileURL) {
    sData = {
        rawfilepath: rawFileURL,
        readyfilepath: "",
        teller: form.value.steller,
        title: form.value.stitle,
        userid: uid,
    }
});
```

Comment: Many thanks Hanna. I updated the code with your suggestion and can now submit the file path to firestore. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that rawfilepath (`this.downloadURL`) is undefined.  You will have to do some debugging to figure out why that is.  It's looks likely that you're trying to use `this.downloadURL` before its value was provided in the callback provided to `getDownloadURL()`.

Remember that functions that return promises are aysnchronous and return immediately, before the work is complete.  So, you should only use `this.downloadURL` **inside** the callback, or some other time when you are absolutely certain that the callback is complete.